# MongoDB Change Streams on bulkWrite()

Tags: mongodb

I am in a situation where I change one document a lot. I have several updates which I send in once by *bulkWrite()*. I would like to limit the number of notifications from a change stream based on *bulkWrite()*. If I do 5x updates on a document, then change stream will notify 5x. It would be nice to get only one notification after all those updates when *bulkWrite()* is done. Is there a way how to achieve that?

Comment: I've found that with ChangeStreams, your best bet is to limit / consolidate writes such that your number of ChangeStream events isn't so noisy.  Have you tried putting your bulkWrite inside a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a different situation, but similar to yours.
I'm updating a document the moment a user changes a field in a form, but in the streams I would like to listen only to the final updated document.

The way I went about it was with a debounce.

The general idea is to store a unique representation of the stream (combination of collection, operation and document), and then have a timeout before you use that stream. If another stream comes in with the same unique id representation, you cancel the previous timeout and create a new one.

Here's a simple example for the `update` operations:

```
const streamMap = new Map();

const debounceStreamExecution = (next, fn) => {

    const streamId = `${next.operationType}_${next.documentKey._id.toString()}` // This could be your own unique representation of a stream.
    const streamItem = streamMap.get(streamId);

    if (streamItem && streamItem.timeout) {
        // Same stream came before, so stop previous execution.
        clearTimeout(streamItem.timeout);
    }

    // We merge previous updates with new ones
    const updateDescription = {
        updatedFields: {
            // Use Lodash _.merge() if you want deep merging
            ...streamItem.updateDescription.updatedFields || {},
            ...next.updateDescription.updatedFields || {}
        },
        removedFields: [].concat(
            streamItem.updateDescription.removedFields || [],
            next.updateDescription.removedFields || []
        )
    };

    // We set our timeout to delay execution
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        streamMap.delete(streamId);
        fn({
            ...next,
            updateDescription
        });
    }, 1000 /* <-- Your delay preference */);

    // We store this stream information.
    streamMap.set(streamId, {
        updateDescription,
        timeout
    });

};

db.collection('aCollection').watch().on('change', next => {
    debounceStreamExecution(next, (result) => {
        console.log('Single stream', result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check MongoDB documentation `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods` 
if you try to do something like this:

```
db.collectionName.bulkWrite(
      [
         { insertOne :
            {
               "document" :
               {
                  "char" : "Dithras", "class" : "barbarian", "lvl" : 4
               }
            }
         },
         { insertOne :
            {
               "document" :
               {
                  "char" : "Taeln", "class" : "fighter", "lvl" : 3
               }
            }
         },
         { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { "char" : "Taeln" },
               "update" : { $set : { "status" : "Critical Injury" } }
            }
         },
         { deleteOne :
            { "filter" : { "char" : "Brisbane"} }
         },
         { replaceOne :
            {
               "filter" : { "char" : "Meldane" },
               "replacement" : { "char" : "Tanys", "class" : "oracle", "lvl" : 4 }
            }
         }
      ]
   );
```

you will get only one result

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : 0,
    "insertedCount" : 2,
    "matchedCount" : 1,
    "upsertedCount" : 0,
    "insertedIds" : {
        "0" : ObjectId("5bdfe0a5bad3d851a4064080"),
        "1" : ObjectId("5bdfe0a5bad3d851a4064081")
    },
    "upsertedIds" : {

    }
}
```

If I can do anything else feel free to ask:).

Comment: You are right the result info is only one. But what I mean is a number of documents in change stream. Let say I update three times the same document and then I execute bulk write. Change stream returns me the same document three times. I would like to get only one document because it's the same document and I don't need it three times.